# Java-DAO: How can I save a default value in a tabel?

Tags: java, database

I have these 2 tables:

```
T1: County- Name - FK_Country
T2: Country - Name
```

And when I want to save a County, I want to choose a default Country, but I receive this error: object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging: local.Country; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging: local.County

Java Code

```
Country country = new Country("USA");

localizationService.saveCountry(country);
localizationService.saveCounty(getForm().getModelObject());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems here:

1. You are creating a new `Country` for each save.
2. You are not associating the `Country` object with `County` before saving.

I would try loading a country from the database. That is, instead of doing:

```
Country country = new Country("USA");
```

Do something along the lines of:

```
Country country = localizationService.findByName("USA");
// My assumption on your model here
County county = getForm().getModelObject();
county.setCountry(country);
localizationService.saveCounty(county);
```

Comment: Ok, the problem was: I dind't knew that the Version column for my table shouldn't be null. I inserted a bunch of info into the tables, leaving the Version column null (this column apparently it's used for JPA). Any, thaks again for your time to answer.